I'm using C# with openxml. How do I delete a cell that contains a formula?
I'm using C# with openxml and Excel 2013. I'm trying to delete a cell that has a formula. I can delete a cell without a formula but when I try to delete it with a formula the excel file gets corrupted.
To duplicate the error create an excel file and set cell A1 to "=A2".
Run the following code and the saved excel file will be corrupted:
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string filePath = "c:\\test\\test.xlsx";
        string worksheetName = "Sheet1";

        //get first row
        SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetdocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true);
        WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetdocument.WorkbookPart;
        Sheet sheet = workbookpart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == worksheetName);
        WorksheetPart worksheetpart = (WorksheetPart)workbookpart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);
        SheetData sheetdata = worksheetpart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().FirstOrDefault();
        Row row = sheetdata.Elements<Row>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.RowIndex == 1);

        //get first cell
        Cell cell = row.Elements<Cell>().FirstOrDefault();
        
        //delete cell 
        cell.Remove();

        //save
        worksheetpart.Worksheet.Save();
        spreadsheetdocument.Save();

        //dispose
        spreadsheetdocument.Dispose();

    }

}



the code work for me (DocumentFormat.OpenXml 3.0.2). the code clear the A1 cell.

did you have a formula in cell A1?

I'm using Excel 2013, VS 2019, .NET Framework 4.7.2, OpenXml 3.0.2

you right, now i see the problem.

My answer is based on the answer here: Removing a formula from Excel using OpenXML
The formula is kept in a separate part of the workbook, and it should be removed from there for data integrity.
In the simple demo you showed, it can be done in one line before saving:
spreadsheetdocument.WorkbookPart
              .CalculationChainPart
              .CalculationChain
              .Elements<CalculationCell>()
              .FirstOrDefault(cc => cc.CellReference == cell.CellReference)?
              .Remove();

In real cases (with dynamic clear of more than one cell), it would probably be more effective to prepare a dictionary of formula cells as demonstrated by other answers in the link I provided.
OpenXml is not ideal for such operations because it accesses the data stored at a very low level, and you need to check how to do each operation. I recommend using EPPlus:
ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(filePath)
{
    var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
    sheet.Cells["A1"].Clear();
    //or  sheet.Cells[1,1].Clear();
    package.Save();
}

(Both OpenXml and EPPlus do not need office installed on the computer).

I already tried that and it still corrupts the file. We use large, complex excel files as templates for our reports and epplus, closedxml, and npoi aren't able to handle them. I think I've got just about everything I need with openxml except for this row deleting. I may be able to workaround the row delete problem but I'd rather fix it if possible.

By deleting the calculation chain part I was able to get this to work for my example. But I found another error. If I copy the formula in cell A1 down to a few cells in my excel template I get another error. When I open the excel file the error is "Removed Records: Shared formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part". Somehow I have to remove a shared formula when I delete a cell but I have no clue how.
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string filePath = "c:\\test\\test.xlsx";
        string worksheetName = "Sheet1";

        //get first row
        SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetdocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true);
        WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetdocument.WorkbookPart;
        Sheet sheet = workbookpart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == worksheetName);
        WorksheetPart worksheetpart = (WorksheetPart)workbookpart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);
        SheetData sheetdata = worksheetpart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().FirstOrDefault();
        Row row = sheetdata.Elements<Row>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.RowIndex == 1);

        //get first cell
        Cell cell = row.Elements<Cell>().FirstOrDefault();

        //delete cell 
        cell.Remove();

        //remove calculation cell from calculation chain
        spreadsheetdocument.WorkbookPart.CalculationChainPart.CalculationChain.Elements<CalculationCell>()
            .FirstOrDefault(cc => cc.CellReference == cell.CellReference)?.Remove();

        //delete calculation chain part if no cells left
        if (spreadsheetdocument.WorkbookPart.CalculationChainPart.CalculationChain.Elements<CalculationCell>().Count() == 0)
        {
            workbookpart.DeletePart(spreadsheetdocument.WorkbookPart.CalculationChainPart);
        }

        //save
        worksheetpart.Worksheet.Save();

        //dispose
        spreadsheetdocument.Dispose();

    }

}

